# ul overflow-x: visible and overflow-y:scroll doesn't work at same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

**TL;DR**
See link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKqKZe for code which also explains my problem.

I want to achieve result like in the image.
[image: Most complex CSS-HTML for me]

**My Code:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="some-div-for-other-purpose">
  <ul class="dynamic-height-list">
    <li>
      <label>Name1</label>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical'
            onclick="toggleGreenDiv()">
      </span>
      <div class="toggle-visibility-green-div">ANYTHING INSIDE IT</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Name2</label>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical'></span>
      <div class="toggle-visibility-green-div">ANYTHING INSIDE IT</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Name3</label>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical'></span>
      <div class="toggle-visibility-green-div">ANYTHING INSIDE IT</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Name4</label>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical'></span>
      <div class="toggle-visibility-green-div">ANYTHING INSIDE IT</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.glyphicon {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }

.dynamic-height-list {
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;

  li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;    

    &:hover {
      background-color: #BBB;
    }
  }
}

.toggle-visibility-green-div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  left: 155px;
  top: 0;
}

.showGreenDiv + .toggle-visibility-green-div {
  display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.glyphicon').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('showGreenDiv');
});
```

**PROBLEM:**
This green div is going inside the main ul list and making it horizontally scrollable instead like image.

> Remove **overflow** property from ul, then it works fine but I can't do that since the list is dynamic and it has to be made scrollable for after max-height
>
> **IMPORTANT:** Also, adding overflow:visible for ul will make it work but at the same
>   time overflow-y should also scroll since list is vertically
>   scrollable. And overflow-x: visible and overflow-y:scroll doesn't work
>   at same time.
>
> NOTE: Since, I want green div to appear adjacent to whatever <'li>'s button is clicked, so it has to be a child of <'li'>. And I don't want to find the position of my <'li'> using javascript. So, please tell if solution exist by changing structure of HTML or modifying css

**EDIT:**
Also, why overflow-x:visible doesn't work same as overflow-y:visible. I mean, why can't putting overflow-x:visible doesn't make it work.

Comment: I see a long question.. I think it will much easier for us to see it in live in snippet or bin. Can you create one please?

Comment: Still, I would have to explain my situation, isn't it? Btw, it's not a long question, it's image and code that makes it long. Just see, so much less text is writtten

Comment: Yes, but if you create a working example of the issue then we dont have to.  Which I just tried and did not work based on your code.  This is what I get plugging you code in (https://jsfiddle.net/6otmvs36/).  I now have to make alot of assumptions just to start debugging it

Comment: Ok fine, I'll add a working example link shortly. Thanks

Comment: @MoshFeu I added the codepen link which explains my problem also

Comment: I can't see the problem in this pen.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/b4bkb.png

Comment: @MoshFeu Would you please open the codepen link I coded!!

Answer (score 1):

Move `overflow-y: scroll` and `max-height` to your parent div so it doesn't cut of after your `width` is reached.

```
.some-div-for-other-purpose {
  max-height: 130px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[Like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrJqmJ)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Later, I realized some people would reply this solution. Kindly visit the codepen link again, I added something to more accurately specify my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Than there is no CSS only solution. If you want the width to be limited you can only use Javascript, sorry.

Comment: Thank you @Tim for confirming. I'll use javascript then. Had overflow-x:visible and overflow-y:scroll would have worked together then my problem would have been solved but don't know why they don't work in this combination.